# how to change size of text while exporting from datagridview to pdf in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, datagridview, itext

I have put all data in datagridview table from database and i have to print this table but the font size in printing page is too small so i want to change the font size of cell rows in printing page.

```
pdfTable.AddCell(cell.Value.ToString());
```

this above line doesn't allow me 2 argument like (cell.Value.ToString(),"arial",14); this gives me error.
so how can i change the font size?

```
//Adding Header row
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
            {

                PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(column.HeaderText));
                cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.Color(0, 240, 240);
                cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;

                cell.PaddingLeft = 20f;
                cell.PaddingTop = 4f;
                pdfTable.AddCell(cell);              
            }           
            //Adding DataRow
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {


                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {

                    iTextSharp.text.Font fon = FontFactory.GetFont("ARIAL", 30);
                    pdfTable.AddCell(cell.Value.ToString());
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: you are using a version of iText that is no longer supported. The current version is iText 7; you are using iText 5 or earlier.

This being said, in your code, you create a variable `fon`, but you never use that variable:

```
iTextSharp.text.Font fon = FontFactory.GetFont("ARIAL", 30);
pdfTable.AddCell(cell.Value.ToString());
```

You should use it like this:

```
iTextSharp.text.Font fon = FontFactory.GetFont("ARIAL", 30);
pdfTable.AddCell(new Phrase(cell.Value.ToString(), fon));
```

One of the advantages of using iText 7 instead of iText 5 is that you can set the font at the level of the table. Once this is done, all the cell will inherit that font, and you won't have to create a new `Phrase` for every cell you add.

Please upgrade to iText 7: https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/NET

Comment: can i ask one more question?

Comment: @deshalkh New questions should be asked in a new post.